# Difference between Include, Extends, Use, Macro, Embed in Twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony, silex

What is the difference between `use` and `include` in Twig?

## [Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation):

> ### include
>
> The `include` statement includes a template and returns the rendered content of that template into the current one:
>
> ```
> ￼{% include 'header.html' %}
> Body here...
> {% include 'footer.html' %}
> ```
>
> ### use
>
> The `use` statement tells Twig to import the blocks defined in `blocks.html` into the current template (it's like macros, but for blocks):
>
> ***blocks.html***
>
> ```
> {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
> ```
>
> ***main.html***
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %}
> {% use "blocks.html" %}
> {% block title %}{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}{% endblock %}
> ```

---

## Possible answer:

I think [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twig-users/f9Vac21WeVk) should explain the difference:

> `include` is to get all the code from an external file and import it 
>   into your actual file at the right location of the call.
>
> `use` is completely different as it parses the linked file to find a 
>   particular section of code and then overwrites the blocks with the 
>   same name, in your current file, with the one found in this external 
>   file.
>
> `include` is like "**go find this file and render it with my page here**".
>
> `use` is "**parse this other file to find block definitions to use instead 
>   of my owns defined here**".
>
> If `use` command finds nothing matching the task, nothing is displayed 
>   at all from this file.

---

## Question

is the explanation correct? are there any other explanations to this difference?

Comment: When using `include` the content will be added into the template directly, whilst using `use` you still need the `block` function to render the "used" blocks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

After months, I am posting an answer for any further reference to this question. I also added some description for `extends` & `import` & `macro` & `embed` for more clearance:

There are various types of inheritance and code reuse in Twig:

---

## Include

**Main Goal:** Code Reuse

**Use Case:** Using `header.html.twig` & `footer.html.twig` inside `base.html.twig`.

**header.html.twig**

```
<nav>
   <div>Homepage</div>
   <div>About</div>
</nav>
```

**footer.html.twig**

```
<footer>
   <div>Copyright</div>
</footer>
```

**base.html.twig**

```
{% include 'header.html.twig' %}
<main>{% block main %}{% endblock %}</main>
{% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
```

---

## Extends

**Main Goal:** Vertical Reuse

**Use Case:** Extending `base.html.twig` inside `homepage.html.twig` & `about.html.twig`.

**base.html.twig**

```
{% include 'header.html.twig' %}
<main>{% block main %}{% endblock %}</main>
{% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
```

**homepage.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
<p>Homepage</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**about.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
<p>About page</p>
{% endblock %}
```

---

## Use

**Main Goal:** Horizontal Reuse

**Use Case:** `sidebar.html.twig` in `single.product.html.twig` & `single.service.html.twig`.

**sidebar.html.twig**

```
{% block sidebar %}<aside>This is sidebar</aside>{% endblock %}
```

**single.product.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'product.layout.html.twig' %}

{% use 'sidebar.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}<main>Product page</main>{% endblock %}
```

**single.service.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'service.layout.html.twig' %}

{% use 'sidebar.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}<main>Service page</main>{% endblock %}
```

**Notes:**

1. It's like macros, but for blocks.
2. The use tag only imports a template if it does not extend another template, if it does not define macros, and if the body is empty.

---

## Macro

**Main Goal:** Reusable Markup with Variables

**Use Case:** A function which gets some variables and outputs some markup.

**form.html.twig**

```
{% macro input(name, value, type) %}
    <input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" }}" />
{% endmacro %}
```

**profile.service.html.twig**

```
{% import "form.html.twig" as form %}

<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>{{ form.input('username') }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.input('password') }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.input('submit', 'Submit', 'submit') }}</div>
</form>
```

---

## Embed

**Main Goal:** Block Overriding

**Use Case:** Embedding `pagination.html.twig` in `product.table.html.twig` & `service.table.html.twig`.

**pagination.html.twig**

```
<div id="pagination">
    <div>{% block first %}{% endblock %}</div>
    {% for i in (min + 1)..(max - 1) %}
        <div>{{ i }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div>{% block last %}{% endblock %}</div>
</div>
```

**product.table.html.twig**

```
{% set min, max = 1, products.itemPerPage %}

{% embed 'pagination.html.twig' %}
    {% block first %}First Product Page{% endblock %}
    {% block last %}Last Product Page{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

**service.table.html.twig**

```
{% set min, max = 1, services.itemPerPage %}

{% embed 'pagination.html.twig' %}
    {% block first %}First Service Page{% endblock %}
    {% block last %}Last Service Page{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

Please note that embedded file (`pagination.html.twig`) has access to the current context (`min`, `max` variables).

Also you may pass extra variables to the embedded file:

**pagination.html.twig**

```
<p>{{ count }} items</p>
<div>
    <div>{% block first %}{% endblock %}</div>
    {% for i in (min + 1)..(max - 1) %}
        <div>{{ i }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div>{% block last %}{% endblock %}</div>
</div>
```

**product.table.html.twig**

```
{% set min, max = 1, products|length %}

{% embed 'pagination.html.twig' with {'count': products|length } %}
    {% block first %}First Product Page{% endblock %}
    {% block last %}Last Product Page{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

**Note:**

It has functionality of both `Use` & `Include` together.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanations. Just I don't understand this: `services.itemPerPag` and `products|length` .. You're setting what to what?

Comment: @Pmpr, can you show an example repository which demonstrates the implementation of `use`? I can't make it work in Symfony 5.2.3 and Twig 3.3.0.

Comment: What exactly is the diference of using use instead of include? I mean - both just include the template....

Comment: @Slowwie {% use %} will include the blocks within the included template without attempting to output anything. It only works with "traitable" templates, ie. only having {% block %} segments, not direct HTML code. {% include %} works the other way around: you include another Twig template to output the included HTML code in your current template.

Answer (score 3):

Twig performance is spectacular, so chances are you will never care, but be aware that **there is a significant difference between using embeds, includes, or macros**.

I set up a little test project to demonstrate it: https://github.com/janklan/twig-benchmark

The readme has all the information you need if you're interested to know more, but the general result is, that for the same task executed in a loop of 100k iterations, the times between individual methods on my computer were as follows (lower is better)

- embed: 4253ms
- include: 3428ms
- macro: 2695ms

---

By the way, the project I shared via Github up generates separate cache directories for each approach (embed/include/macro). If you want to see how different methods in Twig map to the compiled PHP, I recommend you check it out. If you wish to see the cache without having to run the project, check out [a branch called `with-cache`](https://github.com/janklan/twig-benchmark/tree/with-cache/cache)