# OpenCart 3.x - including a new template file

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

I need to add a new OpenCart template file into another template file.

Essentially I've created a new head file in `/theme/customtheme/template/common/` called "header_home.twig".

Then in home.twig, I've changed **{{ header }}** to say **{{ header_home }}**, but it's not displaying anything.

Basically, all I did was copy **header.twig** and rename it to **header_home.twig**, and put in "xxxxx" to see if it was calling the new file, which it's not. Instead, it's not displaying anything.

Here's what my home.twig now looks like:

```
{{ header_home }}
<div id="common-home" class="container">
  <div class="row">{{ column_left }}
    {% if column_left and column_right %}
    {% set class = 'col-sm-6' %}
    {% elseif column_left or column_right %}
    {% set class = 'col-sm-9' %}
    {% else %}
    {% set class = 'col-sm-12' %}
    {% endif %}
    <div id="content" class="{{ class }}">{{ content_top }}{{ content_bottom }}</div>
    {{ column_right }}</div>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

I assume I'm somehow missing a step when it comes to adding a new template file? If someone could help me with adding in a new twig file, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You need to use the [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) function when you want to include other templates. More methods to reuse code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526990/difference-between-include-extends-use-macro-embed-in-twig)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't learn OpenCart 3.x, but I guess you need to change

```
return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
```

to

```
return $this->load->view('common/header_home', $data);
```

in `catalog/controller/common/header.php`.

Answer (score 6):

You can either:

- Change the name of Twig rendering template on the OpenCart level in the controller/common/header as @bogalakon pointed out (preferably to do this via ocmod so that your future OpenCart updates will not overwrite your hack).
- or include another template on the Twig level

I.e.:

```
{{ header }} {# Original rendered to HTML OpenCart header - you can move it to your header_home.twig or just drop it #}
{% include customtheme/template/common/header_home.twig %}
<div id="common-home" class="container">
 ...
```

**Twig** is very powerful template language. And you can do much more than just a simple include! It's nice that OpenCart officially accepted it. But for now it's just Twig 1.24.2. Please refer to the [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/tags/include.html).

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect another template via the {{header_home}} construct, you need to create the header_home.php in the folder `/controller/common/directory`, create the header_home.twig file in the theme `/*theme_name*/template/common/` folder and in the controller , which is responsible for the formation of the page, for example in the directory `/controller/common/home.php`

add a line:

```
'$ data [' header_home '] = $ this-> load-> controller (' common / header_home '); '
```

before:

```
'$ this-> response-> setOutput ($ this-> load-> view (' common / home ', $ data)); '
```

Answer (score 2):

To add your own custom twig file and include it inside another existing one you need to do three things:

1. Create the actual custom twig file.
   In your case it will be:
   `catalog/view/theme/customtheme/template/common/header_home.twig`
2. Create a controller for that twig file. In your case you can just copy:
   `/catalog/controller/common/header.php` and rename that to `header_home.php`. Edit this controller and change the class name to `ControllerCommonHeaderHome` usually on line 2.
3. Lastly, since you are going to include `header_home` inside `home.twig`, edit `/catalog/controller/common/home.php` and add the line `$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header_home');` after `$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');`

That's it. After you've done the steps above, you can now include `{{ header_home }}` inside `home.twig`. If you are editing the files directly, I find that sometimes I need to login to the admin of the website, go to design>theme editor, open up the files I added or changed, hit reset, and save. Refresh your website and you should see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @bogalakon is right but if you update your OpenCart core files you will lose your changes so, I suggest you to copy the `header.php` controller file and rename it to `header_home.php` and then edit the file and replace the line

```
return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
```

with:

```
return $this->load->view('common/header_home', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to give a different value.

For example:

Consider the controller

```
$data['header'] = $this-> load-> controller ('common / header');
```

A variable {{header}} is available in the template

You can place a new template in another file (***header_home.twig***), and then you can immediately download a new template for use:

```
$data['**header**'] = $this-> load-> controller ('common / ***header_home***');
```

If you want use {{**header**}} in the template.

Or,

```
$data['**header_home**'] = $this-> load-> controller ('common / header_home');
```

For use {{**header_home**}} in the template.