# Using 3 templates at the same time with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am having troubles assembling 3 Twig templates, with `{% extends %}` and `{% use %}`.

I know how to assemble 2 templates, thanks to `{% extends %}` but I don't get how to add a third. I got two different types of errors : 

`Circular reference detected for Twig template "home.html.twig", path:
home.html.twig -> twtts.html.twig -> home.html.twig
OR
Template "twtts.html.twig" cannot be used as a trait.`

I don't understand what's wrong in this :

```
{# home.html.twig #}

{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% use 'twtts.html.twig' %}
{% block assets %}
<script src="/assets/js/actions.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block page_title %}Twttr | Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table col-md-6 mt-5" id="twtts">
            {% block twtts %}
            {% endblock %}
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
```

_

```
{# twtts.html.twig #}

{% block twtts %}
{% for twtt in twtts %}
<tr class="">
    <td class="col-md-6">
        <div class="media pr-4 pl-4 pt-4 pb-3">
            <a href="/profile/{{twtt.author_name}}">
            {% if twtt.pp_url is not empty %}
                <img src="{{ twtt.pp_url }}" alt="{{ twtt.author_name }} profile picture" class="align-self-start twtt-thumbnail mr-3 ml-3">
            {% else %}
                <img src="/assets/pp/default_pp.png" alt="PP-Pro" class="align-self-start twtt-thumbnail mr-3 ml-3">
            {% endif %}
            </a>
            <div class="media-body position-relative">
                {% if twtt.rt_author_name is not null %}
                <small class="text-muted position-absolute rtwtt-msg">{{ twtt.rt_author_name }} rtwtted :</small>
                {% endif %}
                <h5 class="mt-0 d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <a href="/profile/{{twtt.author_name}}" class="text-dark">{{ twtt.author_name }}</a>
                    <span>{% if twtt.rt_author_name is not null %}{{ twtt.post_time|date("d/m/Y H:i") }}{% else %}{{ twtt.date|date("d/m/Y H:i") }}{% endif %}</span>
                </h5>
                <p>{{twtt.content|nl2br}}</p>
                <div class="media-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="actions d-flex justify-content-around">
                        <div class="rtwtt {% if twtt.rtwtted == true %}text-success{% endif %}" data-twtt={{ twtt.id }}><span class="rt-nbr">{{ twtt.rtwtts }}</span><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></div>
                        <div class="fav {% if twtt.faved == true %}text-warning{% endif %}" data-twtt={{ twtt.id }}><span class="fav-nbr">{{ twtt.favs }}</span><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

_

```
{# layout.html.twig #}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  {# ... #}
  {% block assets %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

It used to work when the file `twtts.html.twig` was in `home.html.twig` but as I am going to reuse it for a lot of other pages, I was trying to shorten it, and make a file for this template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simply render the content from `twtts.html.twig`, you should use `include`

```
{# home.html.twig #}

{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
....

{% block content %}
<div class="container d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table col-md-6 mt-5" id="twtts">
```

> {% include 'twtts.html.twig' %} <==== Include where you want to render

```
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

See the following thread for difference between `include`, `use` and extend.
[Difference between Include, Extends, Use, Macro, Embed in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526990/difference-between-include-extends-use-macro-embed-in-twig?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer as per you scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer would be clearer if the line where I had to add the `{% include 'twtts.html.twig' %}` was explicitly told, would make more sense to include it at the right place rather than at the top of the document

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion, updated the answer by highlighting the include statement.